# Conda error on update: `conda.core.link:_execute(637): An error occurred while installing package 'None'. AssertionError()`

Tags: python, conda

Today when updating conda via `conda update --all` it downloads several packages and nearly completes installation but at the end, gives

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(637): An error occurred while installing package 'None'.
AssertionError()
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

AssertionError()
()
```

Comment: Having same error ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(637): An error occurred while installing package 'None'

Comment: No solution yet, but open issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8831

Comment: I found that `conda install conda` ended up fixing things for me. That was after trying to remove a bunch of packages with no luck.

Comment: ### I Hate Computers ### on conda github triggered moderator who locked issue without resolution, so no solution there.

Answer (score 3):

The command `conda install conda` worked for me also when `conda install anaconda` failed for me. I am not sure why the latter does not work though. Otherwise I would get the `ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(637)` error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be linked with old packages in the env that are not compatible with the version of the package you are trying to update. Resolved with the following steps:

1. updated packages in the env with dependencies for spyder 3.3.6
2. installed lattest vesrion of conda with

   conda install conda
3. updated spyder with:

   `conda update spyder`

After that everything was fine for me!

Comment: Installing `conda install conda` produces the same error. I'm guessing I should somehow purge the old installation and download a new installer.