# Error installing conda packages: conda.core.link:_execute(696): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::qt-5.9.7-h506e8af_3'

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to update packages, and I'm as it goes through the process it eventually stops and rolls back without updating. I'm trying to run this (I've also tried with other packages like astroML, basemap, nltk, etc with similar effect):

```
conda install conda --update-all
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: | b'Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extens
ion...\n      - Validating: ok\n'
done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(696): An error occurred while installing package
'conda-forge::qt-5.9.7-h506e8af_3'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::qt-5.9.7-h506e8af_3
location of failed script: C:\Users\Mike\Anaconda3\Scripts\.qt-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:         1 file(s) copied.

stderr: 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

return code: 1

()
```

I've already tried out answers for [conda.core.link:_execute(637)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826833/conda-error-on-update-conda-core-link-execute637-an-error-occurred-while-i) and the [chcp error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142058/chcp-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or) with no luck.  If I try to update through the Anaconda Navigator it looks like I'm getting the same results.  I appreciate any help in understanding and resolving this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the most practical solution, but since you already tried the answers from the previous questions, you might just want to re-install conda. It takes a while, but for me that was the only fix that worked.

Unfortunately that means that you'll remove all your environments as well, so this might be the perfect time to create an environment.yml file for them (or pat yourself on the back if you already have them).

Answer (score 0):

i once faced same trouble after 3 hours googling i found the solution
every error which end with statement .qt-post-link.bat it caused by the windows administrator access, so open your CMD as an administrator and then execute the command.

here my result

```
C:\Users\muham\Documents\xxx\python\sample_project>conda install numpy matplotlib scikit-learn pandas
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\xxx\miniconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - matplotlib
    - numpy
    - pandas
    - scikit-learn

lz4-c              pkgs/main/win-64::lz4-c-1.9.2-hf4a77e7_3
  matplotlib         pkgs/main/win-64::matplotlib-3.3.2-0
  matplotlib-base    pkgs/main/win-64::matplotlib-base-3.3.2-py38hba9282a_0
  mkl                pkgs/main/win-64::mkl-2020.2-256
  mkl-service        pkgs/main/win-64::mkl-service-2.3.0-py38h2bbff1b_0
  mkl_fft            pkgs/main/win-64::mkl_fft-1.2.0-py38h45dec08_0
  mkl_random         pkgs/main/win-64::mkl_random-1.1.1-py38h47e9c7a_0
  numpy              pkgs/main/win-64::numpy-1.19.2-py38hadc3359_0
  numpy-base         pkgs/main/win-64::numpy-base-1.19.2-py38ha3acd2a_0
  olefile            pkgs/main/noarch::olefile-0.46-py_0
  pandas             pkgs/main/win-64::pandas-1.1.3-py38ha925a31_0
  pillow             pkgs/main/win-64::pillow-8.0.1-py38h4fa10fc_0
  pytz               pkgs/main/noarch::pytz-2020.1-py_0
  scikit-learn       pkgs/main/win-64::scikit-learn-0.23.2-py38h47e9c7a_0
  scipy              pkgs/main/win-64::scipy-1.5.2-py38h14eb087_0
  threadpoolctl      pkgs/main/noarch::threadpoolctl-2.1.0-pyh5ca1d4c_0
  tk                 pkgs/main/win-64::tk-8.6.10-he774522_0
  xz                 pkgs/main/win-64::xz-5.2.5-h62dcd97_0
  zstd               pkgs/main/win-64::zstd-1.4.5-h04227a9_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

C:\Users\muham\Documents\cxxx\python\sample_project>
```